# How to show district of india map in python basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, mapmyindia-api

I have india basemap in plot result but i want the district / cities of each state also in india map in python. **How to show  cities of states of country in python basemap ?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiAR5.png)

Comment: Your best bet would be to download a shapefile with the cities in each state since basemap doesn't come pre-installed with what you're looking for. Read it in using `m.shapefile()` and then go from there ([link to documentation](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shapefile.html) to read shapefiles on basemap).

Comment: Do you know how to put google map in matplotlib python basemap ?

Answer (score 0):

we can do by reading district shape file and then plotting into matplotlib map.
It will work.I have already done.